# Why do actors often play their last scene on a movie on their first day of filming?

Tags: production, film-industry, acting

I am not even sure this is the case, but it did happen to Lena Headey in 300 and in [this interview (9:30)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dzHRHaDgwc) Ethan Hawke and Keira Knightley agree that it is something that happens all the time, namely that actors are required to play their last scene on a movie script on their first day of filming.

Leaving aside particular cases where this is justified for a more efficient filming schedule, is there a reason for this?

Comment: Not sure how common it is. But given the expense of setting up sets and shots, an efficient filming schedule likely drives most decisions.

Comment: Plus you have the opportunity to do it then when everyone is set up with no rush...and if you need to re-shoot it, you can do that during the course of the production.

Comment: **Speculating:** If the ultimate scenes are wrought with tension or emotion, it sure is a good way to check that the actors are up to it. It also helps ensure they are *alive* for it. Think Brandon Lee in The Crow. They got caught out with Heather O'Rourke in Poltergeist III.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because:

1. The actor will look the same in the last scene as he does in previous ones (Mark Hamill case for example).
2. All the staff will know what they need to aim to (I'm thinking lenses, lights, props etc.)
3. It helps actor to understand what will be the outcome of his character decisions so he can put more emphasis on the key things.
4. The actors and staff are not tired and in their prime conditions for the role (the Avengers "shawarma" scene was problematic because everyone was waaaay out of their movie shape, Evans had a real beard for another movie so he just sat there with prosthetics on his face).

Comment: I've heard "C" before, but I gotta believe they already know because they've read the script.

Comment: The Avengers scene was not in the script. The last scene was the New York fighting. Which from filmmaking logic was better to film at the beginning as this was very physically demanding. But it's just an example.

Comment: That's because the Avengers scene was done way after principal photography was done. It was not planned. So it wouldn't be an issue if they had.

Comment: Also Evens did not have a prosthetic. He hid his beard with his hand.

Comment: Many movies also have alternate endings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had the following idea: first impressions are important. During the first scenes of an actor we are very observant to his impersonation of a character. It might be good for the actor to film these scenes when he has a clear bond with the character. Filming first an ending scene could contribute to establishing this bond, while it could camouflage freshman mistakes made by the actor. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Lauren Bacall once said that she expect from the director to tell her what she was doing in the room she is supposed to exit. If she was washing hands, sleeping, dressing etc.